# build exact debian kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, compilation, debian

I'm searching a way to compile this debian kernel from netinstall image :
https://gemmei.ftp.acc.umu.se/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-cd/debian-11.6.0-amd64-netinst.iso

the version is 5.10.0-20-amd64 smp debian 5.10.158-2 (2022-12-13)

do you know where to search or can i do it ?

i try to search the version in https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v5.x/
but can-t find it ...

Comment: You're not going to find the full Debian version of the kernel in the mainline source tree. You need the mainline kernel `5.10.0-20` plus the Debian patches for version `debian 5.10.158-2`.  See https://kernel-team.pages.debian.net/kernel-handbook/ch-source.html You would also want to use the same toolchain as the Debian team.

Comment: The closest source package seems to be for `debian 5.10.127-2`: https://packages.debian.org/buster-backports/linux-source-5.10  You could patch that source to get to revision/patch-level `158-2`

Comment: thank's ! i forget the patch :/